# Android launching wrong activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

Android is launching wrong activity when I start app.

**Manifest.xml :**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.app.activities.RS_SplashScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.company.app.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/myTheme" >
</activity>
```

I added a new Activity `RS_SplashScreenActivity` and set it as launcher activity. Still it tries to launch `RS_PreviousLauncherActivity` which used to be a launcher activity before adding `RS_SplashScreenActivity`.

I am sure that android chooses wrong launcher activity on account of below logs from console.

**Console :**

```
[2013-10-10 12:03:58 - app] Android Launch!
[2013-10-10 12:03:58 - app] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-10 12:03:58 - app] Performing com.company.app.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity activity launch
[2013-10-10 12:04:01 - app] Uploading app.apk onto device '5C78E6332221CD6A1'
[2013-10-10 12:04:05 - app] Installing app.apk...
[2013-10-10 12:04:12 - app] Success!
[2013-10-10 12:04:12 - app] Starting activity com.company.app.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity on device 5C78E6332221CD6A1
[2013-10-10 12:04:12 - app] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.company.app/.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity }
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.company.app/.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity } from null (pid=4530, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10084
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1783)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:463)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
[2013-10-10 12:04:13 - app] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea why this happens?

**Edit :**

```
public class RS_SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(RS_SplashScreenActivity.this, RS_PreviousLauncherActivity.class);
                RS_SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                RS_SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
```

**Edit :** 
When I remove activity tag for `RS_PreviousLauncherActivity`, it detects correct activity as launcher but when I add activity tag again then it starts selecting wrong activity.

**Edit :**
I get below logs in console. May be this has something to do with my problem.

```
[2013-10-09 10:27:04 - app] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Header$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

And one more thing, this same project works on other machine.

Comment: Try cleaning the project from Eclipse

Comment: Post the code of your RS_SplashScreenActivity

Comment: Are both machines (working and non-working) using the same JDK? The last warning you have in your question might indicate that non-working machine is using an older JDK version.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right click your project and select "**Run As**" > "**Run Configurations...**". Check in the dialog that pops up whether you have "**Launch Default Activity**" selected in the **Android** tab:

[image: Run Configurations Dialog]

It is likely that on the machine that keeps launching the old activity, it was set to launch that specific activity (the second radio button) by accident.

Comment: Wow, thank you! So simple and this had me scratching my head for an hour. The odd thing is that I never modified the start activity to begin with. It just happened on its own somehow. Android Studio bug/glitch?

Comment: This worked of course, it's obvious, no idea why didn't try there. But still no idea why it was added there in the first place, why would it

Comment: This is **Run -> Edit Configurations -> Launch Options -> Default Activity** in Android Studio

Comment: I guess I accidentally set this somehow... This problem was driving me crazy! Thank you!!

Comment: This was set to the wrong activity on my project too. Does android studio set this by default by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall app, and install it again, sometimes appLauncher in your launcher holds old reference, i had similar problem with icon, I changed app icon, but it showed as old one.

Comment: @Akash try my solution if doesn't work tell me, I will post update

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project from Eclipse.

1. Menu->Project->Clean->Select you project-> ok

It will clean the project and generate the binary again. after that install the application and check.

Comment: I guess you have tried uninstall and install again too. then I am sure you have updated wrong AndroidManifest.xml(the bin folder one). please check that and try

Comment: delete the bin folder then and repeat the process

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<application
      ..... 
     android:theme="@style/myTheme" 
>

<activity
    android:name="com.company.app.activities.RS_SplashScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.company.app.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity"
    >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might want to do a splash screen in the traditional way...That way you know it will work, see link:  [How to make a Splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project or uninstall your application. Still it didn't work then delete "gen" folder and then clean your project and run.

Answer (score -2):

Check the code of your **RS_SplashScreenActivity**. check all the time **interval** and **redirection to RS_PreviousLauncherActivity.**

If it doesn't solve your problem the do onething

1: **Right click on project from eclipse**

2: click on **Source**

3: Then click on **Cleanup..**

4: Click on **Finish**

5: Atlast after uninstall the app from your device reinstall it.

It will might fix your problem.

**Edited**

Try this:

```
<application
      ..... 
     android:theme="@style/myTheme" 
>

<activity
    android:name="com.company.app.activities.RS_SplashScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.company.app.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity"     
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.company.app.activities.RS_PreviousLauncherActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Tried. Still tries to launch `RS_PreviousLauncherActivity `. The problem is not in `RS_SplashScreenActivity` because on console logs it prints the name of activity it tries to launch and that is `RS_PreviousLauncherActivity `.

Comment: Do one thing for testing try one thing remove RS_PreviousLauncherActivity from manifest . and try to launch RS_SplashScreenActivity and let me know it is coming or not. @Akash

Comment: The problem in may be splash screen may be. If you will post it i can assist you further..@Akash

Comment: Look at edited question. I added code for RS_SplashScreenActivity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38784/discussion-between-akash-and-andru)