# How does android decide starting activity?

Tags: android

I write two simple activities and give them both the category as `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

How will the android System decide which activity to launch ? In my test, it was launching the `SecondActivity`.

```
 <activity android:name="in.co.madhur.activitiestest.SecondActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="in.co.madhur.activitiestest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: there should be 2 icons as there are 2 entry points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In 2 activities will Put 2 Icons in your launcher screen for each activity.

You need to specify which activity is the default one by adding the following line to your intent-filter:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I understood. But how about removing this category "<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />" from the non-default one. Can you elaborate on the difference ?

Comment: What do you actually want, if you want only one icon and on clicking it you want to launch activity MainActivity then put intent-filter in mainActivity and remove it from secondactivity.

Comment: I want to know the purpose of android.intent.category.DEFAULT

Comment: You will find your answere at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727828/what-is-the-purpose-of-android-intent-category-default